# How to check which mta / mail program is in use?

Tags: email, unix, email-server

Is there a command to tell me what MTA/sendmail a unix system uses?

Thanks very much

Comment: Are you actually on the mail server, or are you trying to figure it out remotely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[root@dev ~]# netstat -tlnp |grep :25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1614/sendmail
```

or

```
[root@dev ~]#  lsof -n -i :25
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sendmail 1614 root    4u  IPv4 1413591375      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:smtp (LISTEN)
```

That should do the trick.

If you can't access the server, telnet to port 25 on it, most servers will tell you.

```
[bart@dev ~]$ telnet mail.gandi.net 25
Trying 217.70.184.11...
Connected to mail.gandi.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 relay4-d.mail.gandi.net ESMTP Postfix
```

Comment: tried the first way and it just says "master" not "sendmail"

Comment: And what doe the other options tell you?

Comment: ah crap, I closed it now, i found out via google that 'master' is postfix

Comment: @Alex, if you look at the /proc filesystem, you can see the command line for "master".  For example, if the PID of `master` is 2804, then `cat /proc/2804/cmdline` shows `/usr/libexec/postfix/master`.  This saves the googling, and makes the identification with postfix unambiguous.